# Encyclopedia Talmudit - Early Volumes

Tags: talmud-gemara

Where can one find the early volumes of Encyclopedia Talmudit for purchase? It seems that very few stores carry the early volume.

Comment: Mizrachi books. https://www.ebay.com/str/jewishbookshop?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0&ssspo=gcO1BBVlT8a&sssrc=3418065&ssuid=&widget_ver=artemis&media=COPY